# Binding URL (http//image) imagebrush datatemplate WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is my XAML datatemplate:

```xml
<DataTemplate>
    <Ellipse Height="40" Width="40">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Photo}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>
</DataTemplate>
```

And my Photo Binding using local image with IP ex : `192.168.1.1/image/image.jpg`

I tried call binding **Photo** but in my `ListView` my image did not appear.

Comment: How is the Photo property declared? Where is the DataTemplate used? Is the DataContext set correctly? Are there any data bindng error messages in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you debug the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting image from a local website, you should include `http://` in the path:

```
public Uri Photo { get; } = new Uri("http://192.168.1.1/image/image.jpg");
```